# How to create a tabbed menu in C#

Tags: c#-3.0

i want to create a tabbed menu in c# using Windows application.so plz suggest some nice article to read about it......

Comment: are you looking for tab pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want tab page control tutorial then [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ColorTabControlExample.aspx) tutorial or [this](http://en.csharp-online.net/TabControl) might help you. You can get more information about Tab Control class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fb09fh2.aspx).

I hope this is what you are looking.

Comment: Thanks for ur article. Helps me a lot